# Last source block can't be recognized

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have these three code blocks, but when i C-c C-c the last one, emacs tells me

> C-c C-c can't do anything useful here

```
#+BEGIN_SRC org
,#+BEGIN_SRC python
print('hello');
,#+END_SRC

,#+RESULTS:
: None
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC org
,#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
print('hello');
,#+END_SRC

,#+RESULTS:
: hello
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python
return 1-2+100
#END_SRC
```

This is code blocks inside code blocks. Am I doing anything wrong that I can't see, or is this some sort of bug?

An even more dense example is this, that gives me the same

```
#+BEGIN_SRC org
,#+BEGIN_SRC python
,#+END_SRC
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC org
,#+BEGIN_SRC python
,#+END_SRC
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python
return 1-2+100
#END_SRC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a + sign in the last line, which should read `#+END_SRC`, not `#END_SRC`.

Comment: I am embarrassed not noticing this. I am a seasoned developer xD Thanks for this.

Comment: :-) Happens to best of us!